# Concrete processes to implement the OpenCV feature matching such as match() and radiusMatch()

Tags: opencv, matching, knn

Hello, I want to improve the feature matching algorithm, so I need to know the current methods of feature matching in `OpenCV`. I have some doubts in its implementation.

Given this method:

```
void DescriptorMatcher::match(const Mat& queryDescriptors, const Mat& trainDescriptors, vector<DMatch>& matches, const Mat& mask = Mat()) const
```

how to find the best match feature?

```
DescriptorMatcher::knnMatch()
```

could any one tell me the concrete algorithm or process of the two methods?